# How can I remove Ubuntu from my dual-boot and replace it with another distribution?

Tags: uninstall

In Windows XP, I right click on *my computer*, select *manage → Disk management*, right click on the Ubuntu partition and choose *Delete logical drive*.

Can I remove Ubuntu like this? If not please suggest a way.

Note: I want to remove ubuntu 10.10 and setup Suse 11.3 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to remove Ubuntu before you install openSUSE; Its installer will offer you to use the old Ubuntu partition on the hard drive.

If you want to check which hard drive and partition this is, in Ubuntu, go to *System → Administration → Disk Utility*. Find your hard disk and parition and look for the "device" field. The openSUSE installer will let you install there, and wipe out all of the data that was there before. It will also install a new boot-loader and detect all of the operating systems on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

This way, your bootloader will be erased and you can not boot window$ anymore.If you want to do this you must repair your window$ installation after deleting the partition.

The easiest way for you is formatting the ubuntu partition in suse installation process.So you can install suse on the free space.

P.S: Here is the safe way to remove ubuntu from a dual-boot machine and fix MBR: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Comment: mamnoon dooste aziz! ;) ;)

Comment: pas ba in hesab az rahe shoma estefade mikonam...

Comment: ye soali! man age ubunto 10.10 ro pak konam suse 11.3 (64-bit) mitoonam rahat nasb konam dg?? yani mikham bedoonam chon 64-bit nokteE pish nemiad??

Comment: It won't be a problem.Read the next answer.It can be done easily.