# How can I replace my distro without affecting my Windows-partition?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, xubuntu

I'm new to Linux.

I recently installed Elementary OS on my machine, next to Windows 7, so I have a dual boot.

Now, I'm not sure Elementary OS is the right distro for me so I would like to replace Elementary Os with Xubuntu, but I want to keep Windows 7.
I did not create a single file in Elementary OS, so I don't need to keep a thing of that.

How can I achieve that?

I found this topic: [How can I remove Ubuntu from my dual-boot and replace it with another distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26894/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-from-my-dual-boot-and-replace-it-with-another-distributi)
This does not answer my question.

During installation, I have get the question *This computer currently has multiple operating systems on it. What would you like to do?*

- Install Xubuntu alongside them (documents, music and other personal files will be kept. You can choose which operating system you want each time the computer starts up)
- Erase disk and install Xubuntu (Warning: This will delete all your programs, documents, photos, music, and any other files in all operating systems.)
- Something else (you can create or resize partitions yourself, or choose multiple partitions for Xubuntu)

I don't have a clue on what to choose, so Elementary is gone, xubuntu gets installed and Windows 7 is kept untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've done this several times because any time I upgrade I like to start from scratch.

When you boot up the LiveCD (.ISO) file always click try, that way you know it works and can mess around during the install process. When you are in the trial you must open disk utility and delete everything except the Windows Partition (NTFS) or if you have a backup partition, Don't worry when you install Grub will be installed and it will sort the boot out.Then you can install to the empty space you created. You may have to "swapoff" the active partitions such as the Linux ones (Ext 4.).

Additionally you can simply install alongside and then erase the old partition, the one you don't want any longer although I would recommend the first one as I have done it and you may have some issue with Grub in the second one.

The latter method can also be done in the "something else option."

Comment: In this topic: http://askubuntu.com/a/26897/20376 it is said that when you delete everything from the partition, the bootloader will be erased and you can not boot Windows anymore. Is this true?

Comment: Yes that is why you must install Ubuntu immediatly. But you can also if you wish to only keep windows you can run boot repair, or if Grub is not appearing you can follow this article on how to reinstall Grub from a live CD:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows Loosing Grub isn't that big of a deal really, but as I said you can always do something else then erase the old partition once installed.