# What is the safe way to replace Ubuntu 12.04 (installed in dual-boot with W7) with OpenSUSE 13.1?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation

This question is related to: 
[How can I remove Ubuntu from my dual-boot and replace it with another distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26894/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-from-my-dual-boot-and-replace-it-with-another-distributi)

Laptop: DELL XPS L502X, 64-bit

Existing OS: Windows 7 + Ubuntu 12.04 (in dual-boot)

I tried to proceed with the installation DVD of OpenSUSE 13.1, at the stage where it asks "New Installation" or "Update an existing system". I do not know what to do next, I am just stuck here, I checked in both the options. The new installation seem to wipe the existing OS and the update will not install the automatic configurations (with all programs).
 I am afraid to loose windows. I do not want to install windows again because it is from the manufacturer when i bought the laptop.

Anyone can provide a step-by-sept guide, or any external link ?

Comment: Definitely new installation with manual partitioning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to partition your drive for another operating system. Use gparted or similar program to break hard drive into segments. Once you do that, select the particular partition when you install OpenSUSE. Please let me know if you do not understand how to partition a drive.